# Why does my math se profile link show the Activity page and not the Profile page as default?

Tags: support

When I clicked the new profile information this week (today 17.4.2015) I seem to have chosen to always show my Activity page as first choice.

That is, when I enter this page:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8530/mats-granvik

I am always shown this page:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8530/mats-granvik?tab=topactivity

What I would like to see is this page:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8530/mats-granvik?tab=profile

I have clicked other users and their pages show the Profile page and not the Activity as first page.

Where can I change this?

Comment: well when I click on the first link I always get the third link. So it is only you that will automatically go on your activity profile when you click on your own profile

Comment: I don't believe you can change this. See this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1

Comment: Thank you for the answer @timmbob

Comment: and @NajibIdrissi I will have a look at that page.

Comment: I think that was the point. You are usually interested in your activity page when looking at your own profile; but you're probably interested in the profile page when looking at other people's profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment one cannot change this.

The defaults for a normal user are "activity" for oneself and "profile" for other users. (A moderator always gets "activity").

The rationale is that it is assumed this is what is most useful (as mentioned in a comment).

The entire thing being pretty new, changes might happen if there is demand (make a feature-request or look if one already exists on MSE), for example that it is different for moderators was not like this right away. 
Options could include,  changing the default, making the choice sticky (as with tabs), or introducing a preferences.

Comment: The request was made and [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253659/259867).